# Using server tags inside of a local ASP.NET page contained in an iframe

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a class that modifies the path of a resource (e.g., a stylesheet) based on that file's last modified time. This is in order to prevent caching of stale resources.

The class works on all "normal" pages, but I can't get it to work in a local ASP.NET page that's rendered inside of an `iframe`. The class is located in `~/App_Code`:

**fingerprint.aspx.cs**

```
public class Fingerprint {
    public static string Tag(string rootRelativePath) {
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] == null) {
            string absolute = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(rootRelativePath);

            DateTime date = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute);
            int index = rootRelativePath.LastIndexOf('/');

            string result = rootRelativePath.Insert(index, "/v-" + date.Ticks);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, result, new CacheDependency(absolute));
        }
        return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
    }
}
```

And in under most circumstances, it works successfully if called as follows:

**somepage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MainSite" CodeFile="somepage.aspx.cs" %>

<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%# Fingerprint.Tag("/path/to/resource.css") %>">
    <!-- other markup -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- other markup -->
</body>
</html>
```

But if I have an ASP.NET page that loads another ASP.NET page inside an `iframe`, it doesn't seem to get called. Example:

**parent.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MainSite" CodeFile="parent.aspx.cs" %>
<asp:Panel ID="Container" runat="server">
    <iframe id="testFrame" src="child.aspx"></iframe>
</asp:Panel>
```

**child.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MainSite" CodeFile="child.aspx.cs" %>
<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%# Fingerprint.Tag("/path/to/resource.css") %>">
    <!-- other markup -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- other markup -->
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any errors, but `Fingerprint.Tag` doesn't seem to even be getting called. I just get an empty string in the `href` portion of the `<link>` tag where the path to my stylesheet would normally be.

Is there a trick to getting server tags to work inside of local ASP.NET pages contained in iframes? I'm using ASP.NET WebForms (no other choice, client requirement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing `<%# Fingerprint.Tag("/path/to/resource.css") %>` to `<%=Fingerprint.Tag("/path/to/resource.css") %>`? Changing `#` to `=`.

As far as I know, `<%# ... %>` is more like a data binding syntax.

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you! Of course, that makes me wonder now, why the `<%#` syntax is required on the other pages. If I try to use the `<%=` syntax, I get syntax errors. I'm thinking perhaps it's because the `CodeFile`s for the other pages are in VB.NET, and the `CodeFile` for the page in the iframe is in C#. I come from a Python/Django/Flask and PHP/Laravel background, so I'm still getting used to this .NET stuff. Thank you!

Comment: @AndroidNoobie No, it's not due to VB.NET or C#, the `<%#` syntax is usually used in  template of a control, such as Columns -> ItemTemplate in a GridView, then you invoke GridView.DataBind method, the `<%#` syntax will work in this case. The `<%=` syntax is a syntax that invoke a server side method then have the return value in place the location where it is around normal html code, it has nothing to do with "data binding".